# Broken PHP upgrade?

Tags: apache-http-server, php, homebrew

I recently upgraded PHP through Homebrew. When using terminal command `PHP -i` I'm getting `PHP Version => 7.2.2` as expected.  However, when running `phpinfo();` on localhost I get **PHP Version 5.6.30** instead.

I have already restarted Apache (`$ sudo apachectl -k restart`), unlinked php56 (`$ brew unlink php56`) and tried ports :80 and :8080.

What am I missing?
How can I locate and completely uninstall php56?

edit:
@PatrickMevzek From localhost/phpinfo...

```
Apache Version  Apache/2.4.28 (Unix) PHP/5.6.30
Apache API Version  20120211
Hostname:Port   127.0.0.1:0
User/Group  _www(70)/70
Max Requests    Per Child: 0 - Keep Alive: on - Max Per Connection: 100
Timeouts    Connection: 60 - Keep-Alive: 5
Virtual Server  No
Server Root /usr
Loaded Modules  core mod_so http_core prefork mod_authn_file 
mod_authn_core mod_authz_host mod_authz_groupfile mod_authz_user 
mod_authz_core mod_access_compat mod_auth_basic mod_reqtimeout 
mod_include mod_filter mod_mime mod_log_config mod_env mod_headers 
mod_setenvif mod_version mod_slotmem_shm mod_unixd mod_status 
mod_autoindex mod_negotiation mod_dir mod_userdir mod_alias mod_rewrite 
mod_php5 mod_hfs_apple2
```

From Terminal php -i

```
PHP Version => 7.2.2

System => Darwin zJorgeMBP.local 16.7.0 Darwin Kernel Version 16.7.0: 
    Thu Jan 11 22:59:40 PST 2018; 
    root:xnu-3789.73.8~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
Build Date => Feb  1 2018 11:46:13
Configure Command =>  
  './configure' '--prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/php72/7.2.2_13' 
  '--localstatedir=/usr/local/var' 
  '--sysconfdir=/usr/local/etc/php/7.2' 
  '--with-config-file-path=/usr/local/etc/php/7.2' 
  '--with-config-file-scan-dir=/usr/local/etc/php/7.2/conf.d' 
  '--mandir=/usr/local/Cellar/php72/7.2.2_13/share/man' 
  '--enable-bcmath''--enable-calendar' '--enable-dba' '--enable-exif' 
  '--enable-ftp' '--enable-gd-native-ttf' '--enable-mbregex' 
  '--enable-mbstring' '--enable-shmop' '--enable-soap' 
  '--enable-sockets' '--enable-sysvmsg' '--enable-sysvsem' 
  '--enable-sysvshm' '--enable-wddx' '--enable-zip' 
  '--with-freetype-dir=/usr/local/opt/freetype' '--with-gd' 
  '--with-gettext=/usr/local/opt/gettext' '--with-iconv-dir=/usr' 
  '--with-icu-dir=/usr/local/opt/icu4c' 
  '--with-jpeg-dir=/usr/local/opt/jpeg' '--with-kerberos=/usr' 
  '--with-mhash' '--with-ndbm=/usr' 
  '--with-png-dir=/usr/local/opt/libpng' '--with-xmlrpc' 
  '--with-zlib=/usr' '--with-readline=/usr/local/opt/readline' 
  '--without-gmp' '--without-snmp' 
  '--with-libxml-dir=/usr/local/opt/libxml2' 
  '--with-pdo-odbc=unixODBC,/usr/local/opt/unixodbc' 
  '--with-unixODBC=/usr/local/opt/unixodbc' '--with-bz2=/usr' 
  '--with-openssl=/usr/local/opt/openssl' '--enable-fpm' 
  '--with-fpm-user=_www' '--with-fpm-group=_www' '--with-curl' 
  '--with-xsl=/usr' '--with-ldap' '--with-ldap-sasl=/usr' 
  '--with-mysql-sock=/tmp/mysql.sock' '--with-mysqli=mysqlnd' 
  '--with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd' '--disable-opcache' '--enable-pcntl' 
  '--without-pear' '--enable-dtrace' '--disable-phpdbg' 
  '--enable-zend-signals' '--with-sodium=/usr/local/opt/libsodium'
Server API => Command Line Interface
Virtual Directory Support => disabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /usr/local/etc/php/7.2
Loaded Configuration File => /usr/local/etc/php/7.2/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => /usr/local/etc/php/7.2/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed => (none)
PHP API => 20170718
PHP Extension => 20170718
Zend Extension => 320170718
Zend Extension Build => API320170718,NTS
PHP Extension Build => API20170718,NTS
Debug Build => no
Thread Safety => disabled
Zend Signal Handling => enabled
Zend Memory Manager => enabled
Zend Multibyte Support => provided by mbstring
IPv6 Support => enabled
DTrace Support => available, disabled
```

and from `httpd -t -D DUMP_RUN_CFG`

```
ServerRoot: "/usr/local/opt/httpd"
Main DocumentRoot: "/usr/local/var/www"
Main ErrorLog: "/usr/local/var/log/httpd/error_log"
Mutex default: dir="/usr/local/var/run/httpd/" mechanism=default 
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
PidFile: "/usr/local/var/run/httpd/httpd.pid"
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="_www" id=70 not_used
Group: name="_www" id=70 not_used
```

Comment: Show your Apache configuration related to PHP.

Comment: Sure @PatrickMevzek. I edited to add Apache config from both versions.

Comment: @JakeGould typing `httpd -V` I get `-D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="/usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf"`instead of `/usr/local/etc/apache2/2.4/httpd.conf`... so I opened httpd.conf but there is no phpX_module, neither 5 nor 7.